# Is there any way we can modify Json data coming in the network tab of chrome and see the changes in the web page?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

The webpage Template loads data via some json data we get from the endpoint.
I have a Rest Api and a Angular Front end . The Angular app populates the template from the data coming in from the rest api which we can see in the Network Tab  of Chrome Developer Tools.

Is there any way we can modify the Rest data in Network tab and see the changes that occurs in the Webpage.
Is that even possible, It might sound a stupid question but i guess this might be a very special tool if there is not much interaction between the Back end and Front end teams.

I am not quite sure if i am able to explain it properly but this was the best i could edit please bear with me thanks

Just a Screen Shot of the type of data in Network tab.
[Sample Data Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzxAr.png)

Comment: If not possible in chrome, you could use fiddler to tamper the response before passing it to your browser.

Comment: how can you please just give a overview for same , i want to use it in the same webpage but with diff response

Comment: I recently found this blog [The tool that gives you Superpowers – Part 1](http://develop1.net/public/post/Fiddler2-The-tool-that-gives-you-Superpowers-Part-1.aspx) which could give an idea how to use it for your means.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible from chrome's network tab. You have to use `BurpSuite` for example which is available in Kali linux as a default. With that you can intercept http requests and responses and modify it's payload.
You can get it from here: https://portswigger.net/burp/

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not able to modify XHR data as you can other sources. What I do is just copy the file to my local drive and temporarily modify it's source. I test responses from API's using Postman and it's pretty awesome.

I have to say I'm a little bit afraid for you though. It's not a great idea to be consuming services from external api's from the client side. Are your API keys and passwords hanging out in that client side code somewhere?